# Describing the kernel of $\rho : \mathbb{Z}^p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, $\rho(x_1, \ldots x_n) = a_1 x_1 + \cdots +a_n x_n \pmod p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $p$ a prime, consider the mapping $$\rho : \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$$ defined by $$\rho(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n \pmod p.$$ I want to find the kernel of $\rho$ for the general $n$. I only knew that for $n=2$, the vectors $(-a_2,a_1), (0,p), (p,0)$ are in $\ker\rho$, but I do not know how to express the kernel as a set.

How does one find the kernel of this mapping for general $n$?

Comment: Since $\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_k + p, \ldots, x_n) = \rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n$), $\rho$ factors through the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ to a map $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, which we can just regard as a linear functional $\widetilde{\rho}$ on the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ over the prime field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, namely the one given by $$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & \cdots & a_n\end{pmatrix}$$ in the standard basis. In particular, except when $\rho$ is the zero map, the kernel of $\widetilde{\rho}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ and so has has $p^{n - 1}$ elements.

Comment: I'm confusing why there are $p^{n-1}$ elements in kernel of $\bar{\rho}$?

Comment: If $\rho$ is not the zero map, $\widetilde{\rho}$ is not the zero functional, and so the kernel of $\widetilde{\rho}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$. But this hyperplane is itself a perfectly good $(n - 1)$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and so it has $p^{n - 1}$ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_k + p, \ldots, x_n) = \rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n$), $\rho$ factors through the quotient map $\pi: \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ to a map $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, which we can just regard as a linear functional $\widetilde{\rho}$ on the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ over the prime field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, namely the one given by $$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & \cdots & a_n\end{pmatrix}$$ in the standard basis. In particular, except when $\rho$ is the zero map, the kernel of $\widetilde{\rho}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ and so has has $p^{n - 1}$ elements.

Since the kernel of $\pi$ is $$(p \mathbb{Z})^n = \{(p y_1, \ldots, p y_n) : y_1, \ldots, y_n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$$ which is precisely the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of the $n$-tuples ${\bf e}_k := (0, \ldots, 0, p, 0, \ldots, 0)$ (which has $p$ in the $k$th slot and zeroes in the other slots), $\ker \rho$ is the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations
$$y_1 {\bf e}_1 + \ldots + y_n {\bf e}_n + z_1 {\bf x}_1 + \ldots + z_{n - 1} {\bf x}_{n - 1},$$
where $$\{\widetilde{\bf x}_1, \ldots \widetilde{\bf x}_{n - 1}\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_p^n$$ is a basis of the hyperplane $\ker \widetilde{\rho}$ and the ${\bf x}_k$, $k = 1, \ldots, n$, are any choices of respective preimages of $\widetilde{\bf x}_k$ under $\pi$. The representation of any element of the kernel of $\rho$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of the above form is not unique, but we make it unique by insisting that $0 \leq z_1, \ldots, z_{n - 1} < p$.

In particular, if $n = 2$ (and again, $\rho$ is not the zero map, so that $(a_1, a_2) \neq (0, 0)$), $\ker \widetilde{\rho}$ is $1$-dimensional and so is spanned by $(-a_2, a_1) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^2$. Thus,
$$\ker \rho = \{y_1 {\bf e_1} + y_2 {\bf e_2} + z (-a_2, a_1) : y_1, y_2, z \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$