# Lattice basis for lattice consisting of the set of integer solutions of $a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_1 x_n = 0 \pmod q$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-lattices

Consider the following set
$$ 
\bigl\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid \; 
a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n  = 0 \!\pmod q \bigr\}.
$$

Clearly, this set is a lattice. But I cannot find a basis for it. How would one identify a basis for this lattice?

Comment: Try some small examples: $n=1$ or $n=2$. What do you notice about the resulting lattice? How does it depend on the coefficients $a_1, \dots, a_n$?

Comment: Thanks! 
For $n=1$ it contains exactly all $x$ such $a_1 x_1 = k \cdot q$ for some $k$? (The same for ($n=2$, it contains all $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = k \cdot q$)? Put another way, for $n=1$, it contains all $x_1$ such that $x_1 \cdot (k' \cdot q + r) = k \cdot q$, where $k' \cdot q +r = a_1$? But I do not know how to take it from here.

Comment: dup: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194963/948125

Comment: @GarethMa That answer covers only the cases where $q$ is a prime number. The answer is a bit more complicated if we want the lattice described by a congruence like
$$2x_1+3x_2+5x_3\equiv0\pmod{30}$$
or
$$6x_1+10x_2+15x_3\equiv0\pmod{30}.$$ Mind you, I still suspect the question to be a duplicate of some other.

Comment: Have  you heard of Smith Normal Forms? They can be applied here.

Comment: @GarethMa Furthermore, that answer does not describe a basis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not straightforward. These are called q-ary lattices. Appendix A.6 of this thesis:

http://doi.org/10.17638/03003839

explains a way of getting a basis. Hope it helps.